# Error while sending data with POST request in Android

Tags: java, android

I always get the same error while sending username and password to server. I need to send data as content type:form-data, because server isn't responding on any other type.[image] I tested in postman and it's ok, but when I am trying to send it in code, it's not working. Can someone help me, thanks!!

```
  public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        
                String userName;
                String password;
        
                public Login(String user, String pass) {
                    userName = user;
                    password = pass;
                }
        
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
        
                }
        
        
         
 

protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .build();
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
    RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("user",userName)
            .addFormDataPart("pass",password)
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://www.autotrack.rs/android_juzna_backa/login.php")
            .method("POST", body)
            .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                try {
                    Call call = client.newCall(request);
                    Response response = call.execute();
                    System.out.println(response.body().string());
    
                }catch (Exception m)
                {
                    Log.d("Mytag", m.getMessage());
                }
                if(!response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    try {
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected: "+response);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean okhttp3.Response.isSuccessful()' on a null object reference

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226585/discussion-on-question-by-nikola-stankovic-error-while-sending-data-with-post-re).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfectly fine for me:

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("user","pera")
  .addFormDataPart("pass","1111")
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://www.autotrack.rs/android_juzna_backa/login.php")
  .method("POST", body)
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

In your code I see that you execute the same request twice, maybe this is the issue?

Comment: It's not working, again the same response.

Comment: How I can send my own parameters like username and password with this code? I don't understand. Where in this code I need to add my use and pass?

Comment: I updated again, you need to change only one line.

Comment: I edited my code from postman, but it's not working again..I don't know what is the problem...

Comment: @NikolaStankovic But does it work in postman?

Comment: Can you send a test credentials? So I can login.

Comment: user:pera pass:1111

Comment: I posted a picture here in postman, for test. Try to send data as json, it will not work. Only form-data will work. @MPetrychko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226580/discussion-between-mpetrychko-and-nikola-stankovic).

Comment: @NikolaStankovic I updated the answer, this code works fine for me, try removing your second call with the same request.